# search for exact string from column

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

i have table called contracts in database, this table have column called shop_id

shop_id have many result, it can be like this:

132

133-134-135

3126-3127-125

126-127-128

so i want to get all data where shop_id = 126

so I'm using Like %''

but in this case if i searched for shop_id=3126 it will get the information 
for anything have 126 like 3126 or 4126 and like so.

so how can i search for exact shop id from this column 
so if i searched for 126 i want to get the record  where column contain exact 126.

Comment: If you want the rows where the Id is preceisely `126` dont use LIKE

Comment: `so i want to get all data where shop_id = 126`, `so I'm using Like %''`, you already have it, dont use the like statement. Whats the real question...

Comment: The choice to keep many shopId in the same column separated by a dash is wrong on many levels. They are called Relational Database Systems for a reason.

Comment: Ahhh!  I knew more than one piece of info was sometimes being represented there - multiple ShopIds kind of explains `126-127-128`.

Comment: @Codexer yes i'm asking because the like is not good, so i asked here because i want another way.

Comment: @ Steve ,

yes i know that's wrong, but the customer forced me in the last min that he want many shops in one contract, and I couldn't change the hole database for him. I worked more than 5 months on the project, i cant repeat it from scratch.

Comment: @Plutonix,

yes exactly, i used `-` to separate between the shops id, and again i know that's a wrong way to do it but the customer forced me in the last min that he want many shops in one contract.

Comment: Thats why customers/users should have no say in app or DB design.  its a Horrific idea.  Adding a m:m or 1:m relationship ought not require starting from scratch.

Comment: @Plutonix , unfortunately, the deal was that every contract need one shop, and i design the database on this, after more than 5 he changed every thing so this is the easiest way to do it . is there a solution ??
and in my case its need to start from scratch, because i have 3 tables connected to gather, customers , shops, contracts, contract connected with customers and shop id, it was perfect before the many shops in one contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select *
 From  YourTable 
 Where charindex('-126-','-'+shop_id+'-')>0
```

Comment: first of all thank you its a pleasurable solution,

and yes i know that's wrong, but the customer forced me in the last min that he want many shops in one contract, and I couldn't change the hole database for him. I worked more than 5 months on the project, i cant repeat it from scratch.

Comment: @RabeeaQabaha Happy it helped.  I've inherited much worse and far uglier structuctures  :).

Answer (score 3):

You'r question is not very clear but I think you mean th shop_id contains more than one id

If I'm right, you need below query:

```
select *
from contacts
where shop_id like '126-%' 
   or shop_id like '%-126' 
   or shop_id like '%-126-%' 
   or shop_id = '126'
```

Keep in mind that this is not a good database design.